# how to deploy symfony over http and https?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, symfony

We have a symfony project deployed and working ok but now we want to enable https.

We created and enabled another virtualhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName      project.domain.net

DocumentRoot /home/user/dev/project/web
<Directory /home/user/dev/project/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
<Directory /home/user/dev/project>
  Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project.test_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project.test_access.log combined


SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/wildcard.crt
```

We can navigate to https://project.domain.net and it seems ok but when we check

```
    $request->getUri();
```

the result is http://project.domain.net, so it is ***http*** instead of ***https***.

Why is that? how to fix?

UPDATE:
We added the config given by @Leroy and the result is:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https
REQUEST_METHOD        GET
REQUEST_SCHEME         http
SERVER_NAME zerbikatdesa.sare.gipuzkoa.net
SERVER_PORT  80
```

and the $request->getUri still returns the http insted of https

Comment: (a) are you behind a proxy or load balancer? (b) why is this tagged Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Usually applications must determine themselves which urls require ssl. In symfony you can configure routes to require ssl. Then the application can force ssl on those pages. But based on your request, all of your pages should be https.

Symfony uses 2 ways to determine if a route is secure. When you are behind a proxy, like a loadbalancer, you have to allow that proxy in the `trusted_proxies` and `trusted_headers` (usually there are env variables for you to configure). The proxy should also send a header that the page is loaded over https.

If you are not behind a proxy, like you do by defining a second vhost directing to the filesystem, you have to tell symfony a route is loaded over https. The same request header should be passed to the application.

So the following should fix it.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</VirtualHost>
```

I also see you are using the `/web` subdirectory for public access. Are you still using Symfony version 2?

Comment: No, it's version 3. I'll try this, thanks.